# Get URL Query parameter in an API call C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been doing some research on how to get query string parameters from a URL in C# through an API call and I could not find any relevant information on this. I found a bunch of sources on how to do it in PHP but that is not what I'm using.

I also don't know if I have to set up endpoints to accept the query string parameters as part of a call but I believe I do.

All of my Restful API currently works on URL paths so everything that I want to parse through to my backend is separated with a `/` and I don't want that. I would like to parse all information for processing through query strings and parse only specific path locations using `/`.

This is how my endpoints are currently set up.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "api/v1/{controller}/{id?}/{id1?}/{id2?}/{id3?}/{id4?}/{id5?}/{id6?}");
});
```

This is one of my API calls

```
[HttpGet("/api/v1/Templates/{customerId}")]
public List<string> GetTemplates(string customerId)
{
    return templatesService.GetTemplates(customerId);
}
```

I would like to parse my customer ID as `http://localhost:0000/api/v1?customerId=1`

Example with extra parameters:

```
[HttpPost("/api/v1/Templates/{customerId}/{templateName}/{singleOptions}/{multiOptions}")]
public string GetReplacedTemplate(string customerId, string templateName, string singleOptions, string multiOptions)
{
    return templatesService.GetReplacedTempalte(customerId, templateName, singleOptions, multiOptions);
}
```

So here I have 2 extra parameters which are `SingleOptions` and `MultiOptions`. Main controller is `Templates`.

I think even `TemplateName` should be parse as a Query as I feel like its extra param too.

This is not a problem that is required to solve as using `/` to separate each parameter works fine but I really want to know how to parse query strings as well.

Comment: `http://localhost:0000/api/v1?customerId=1` what would that do? that route would theoretically lead to `Index/Home`. but what to do there with a customer ID?

Comment: P.s. you shouldn't use port 0. Altough technically possible, it's officially reserved and should be avoided.

Comment: You could use `public List<string> GetTemplates([FromRoute] string customerId)`. POST method use [FromBody] to get the request body

Comment: Isn't Query string params used for parsing data to the backend? How would `http://localhost:0000/api/v1?customerId=1` leader to `Index/Home`. Is there something I'm unaware of with Query strings?

Comment: @JHBonarius I put port 0000 as example my actual port is different. FYI

Comment: The query string can be used to add a "query": i.e. You can pass key-value pairs for extra information. But what are you querying? Your path isn't pointing to any controller. Thus it will result to the default controller (Likely HomeController) and the default action (Likely Index).

Comment: Okay, I now understand what you mean. Let me provide a better example where this is going to be very useful as I have a massive API call that has a massive amount of extra things to parse. I will add it to my main question. Take a look in 2 mins after I update.

Comment: @nilsK I have tried your way and I keep getting a 404 not found. I have set up a basic HttpGet request `[HttpGet("api/v1/templates")]`. Using postman I post `http://localhost:0000/api/v1/templates?customerId="blablabla"` In my function and all I'm doing is just returning what I parse in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually dont answer my own Questions but here it is for others to view.

To take Query string parameters in C# through an API call is actually easy.

Using the `[FromQuery]` DataBinding on your parameter will allow you to take what ever you parse it :)

```
[HttpGet("/api/v1/Templates")]
public string GetTemplatesQuery([FromQuery] string customerId)
{
    return customerId;
}
```